# Functionality of VIEW's with WHERE

Tags: mysql, performance, view, where-clause

I'm trying to find out more about MySQL VIEW's, and I'm still quite confused (especially, about the details)

If I get it right, a view is nothng more than a stored SELECT query that gets used. But my problem starts, when I want to use certain values for the WHERE clause inside of the VIEW.

Lets suppose, we have this VIEW:

```
SELECT `user`.`id`, `userrole`.`key` AS `role`, `userstatus`.`key` AS `status`
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN `userrole`
ON `userrole`.`id` = `user`.`userrole_id`
LEFT JOIN `userstatus`
ON `userstatus`.`id` = `user`.`userstatus_id`
```

Now, this would deliver a List of ALL users, with their current role / status

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id |  role | status |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | admin | active |
|  2 |  user | active |
|  3 |  user | active |
|  4 | admin | active |
| .. |   ... |    ... |
+----+-------+--------+
```

Now, I just want to know the role / status of the user with the `ID` 3 - so I would have to do an additional `SELECT` on the `VIEW`, with `WHERE id = 3`, right? But if I do that, what will happen exactly?

Will the `VIEW` still `SELECT` all the users, and then the whole data will be dropped, and only the `id = 3` will be displayed? Or will it be optimized so that the `VIEW` only selects `user.id = 3` ?

I'm confused about the performance aspect of this - since if I would have 1 million users, using a `VIEW` for this would be a rather bad idea. But on the other hand, I would save myself to use the whole `SELECT` with all the `JOIN`'s every time, if I have the `VIEW` for this.

So how exactly does the `VIEW` act? As simple SUBQUERY, or is it more optimized if you add a `WHERE` when selecting a `VIEW`?

I guess if it acts like a SUBQUERY, a `STORED PROCEDURE` with parameters will always be better than a `VIEW`, then (if you have `WHERE` parameters that vary)?

Thanks for the informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be optimized.

You can think of the view as a macro or an alias. At runtime when you use the view the whole SQL text of the view is expanded into the query that uses the view. Then the query optimizer picks only those columns and rows that are actually used in the combined query.

if you type

```
SELECT `id`, `role` FROM YourView
WHERE `status` = 4
```

it will be expanded into

```
SELECT `id`, `role` FROM 
(
SELECT `user`.`id`, `userrole`.`key` AS `role`, `userstatus`.`key` AS `status`
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN `userrole`
ON `userrole`.`id` = `user`.`userrole_id`
LEFT JOIN `userstatus`
ON `userstatus`.`id` = `user`.`userstatus_id`
)
WHERE `status` = 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hoped it would be like that!